# Excel Increment index by 1 for each new week

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a calendar document which I use and in this document I have an index value which should add 1 for each new week. So week 1 has value 1, week 53 has value 53, then week 1 of the new year should have value 54. Any idea how i can achieve this ? I have dates available, as well as week of year as a value.

I solved it for the first year by using this formula but it's giving me trouble for the next years as it doesn't take into account the short weeks at the end of the year.

[image: Preview image]

Here you see the problem: Week 1 of 2018 should have an index value of 107

[image: trouble]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe start your count with `1` and then, starting from row 2, use the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(YEAR(A2)>YEAR(A1),WEEKDAY(A2)=1),B1+1,B1)
```

This should return the following results:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking of posting an answer using weeknum, but this is better and shorter.

Comment: Thanks @Tom ! I was also tempted by `WEEKNUM` solution :)